# Superposition between disparity map and rectified image

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to fusion the disparity map with the rectified image by using a superposition of the two images.
I have my disparity map and i want to superpose it on the rectified image, to get the (x,y,z) value for every pixel.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the OpenCV documentation? https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/

Comment: Than's for your reply. Yes but i didn't find what function to use for that, i'm a 
beginner in image processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a complex problem that won't be solved with a single function. I found this tutorial on the OpenCV.org. I think this will help you get started.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html